# Paging with WebSockets in Sails

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io, sails.js

I have an existing web app with an ExtJS front end and Sails back end. Currently the app uses XHR for data interchange but I wish to switch to Websockets.

Reading the [Sails Docs](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/web-sockets/resourceful-pub-sub) it says that a call to `io.socket.get` will subscribe the client to the returned set of records. When paging however I'm only interested in receiving server-sent events for the current page of records.

Is there some means of unsubscribing records as the user pages?

Comment: So your paging is client side? You load all records but show only some of them?

Comment: Paging is server-side, I load 25 records at a time. I'm only interested in receiving server events for the records that are currently displayed. To clarify my question, when the user loads the next 25 records the client will presumably still be subscribed to the first page of records.

I could certainly do some filtering on the messages received and only act on those for records which are currently on the client but I wondered if there was an API for unsubscribing to those records that no longer exist on the client?

Comment: There is no blueprint action for unsubscribing, but you can just  quickly create an action for unsubscribing. Better create a findForPagination Action and then unsub all other instances except those you queried.

Comment: @ju_ thanks. a findForPagination action sounds like a good way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

`io.socket.get()` will only subscribe you if you are using the [Blueprint API](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/blueprint-api) of sails. That being said have a look at [find where](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/blueprint-api/find-where) and set the `limit` and `skip` properties accordingly. So you will only be subsribed to the instances which are queried.

```
var page = currentPage;
var amount = 30;

io.socket.get('/entry?skip=' + page * amount + '&limit=' + amount, function (entries) {});
```